# Image hover caption with zoom effect in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am unable to align image to the width of caption with maintaining the gutter width. I am using bootstrap and also the image is flowing outside the div on hover. Can anybody help me out ?

This is what i am trying to achive : https://awwapp.com/s/43b68655-83a6-4133-ab28-0ec9a4152316/

Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbxOMq

HTML :
    
        
        
          HOTSPOT TEXTf

```
<div class="col-md-4 hotspot-wrapper">
    <img src="https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/hd-widescreen-wallpaper-3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
    <div class="hotspot-text">
      HOTSPOT TEXTf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 hotspot-wrapper">
    <img src="https://newevolutiondesigns.com/images/freebies/hd-widescreen-wallpaper-3.jpg" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
    <div class="hotspot-text">
      HOTSPOT TEXTf
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hotspot-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.hotspot-text {
  width:100%;
    height: 102px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  color:#fff;
}  
.hotspot-wrapper:hover .hotspot-text {
  bottom: 0;
}

.hotspot-wrapper img {

  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.hotspot-wrapper:hover img {
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
transform:scale(1.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your CSS for these two classes like this, so the hotspot for the text will be aligned with the image :

```
.hotspot-text {

    height: 102px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    transition: all .2s linear;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    color:#fff;
}  
.hotspot-wrapper:hover .hotspot-text {
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

And you should overwrite the padding on the left and on the right set there by default with bootstrap. Like that, the image will have the full width of the div.

```
.col-lg-4 ,.col-md-4,col-sm-4,col-xs-4{
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/4acexxgs/1/)

Comment: This does not work, i have tried this it still creates some space between image and text div.

Comment: You mean when you hover the div and before the transition ends?

Comment: Yes. Its does not look smooth

Comment: How about this : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/4acexxgs/1/) , I will edit the answer as well.